# How to get the url to insert as a data with Redux Form?

Tags: url, react-redux, redux-form, react-dropzone

I was able to get the url in the attachment field but for the redux form it was empty, how is possible to pass the value of the url to the redux form? Below is the code and the screenshot:

```
<div className="FileUpload">
   <Dropzone
     onDrop={this.onImageDrop.bind(this)}
     multiple={false}
     accept="image/*">
<div>Drop an image or click to select a file to upload.</div>
   </Dropzone>
</div>
   <div className="form-group">
     <label htmlFor="attachment">Attachment:</label><br />
       <input className="form-control" focus placeholder="attachment" type="text" name="attachment" ref="attachment" value={this.state.uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl} />
        {this.state.uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl === '' ? null :
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.uploadedFile.name}</p>
            <img src={this.state.uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl} alt="" />            
        </div>}
        </div>
        <div className="ui small image">
          <img src={this.props.workrequest.attachment} alt="" />
        </div>
```

[the url in the attachemnt field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phL6e.png)

The first one is using the React Dropzone to get the url but for the Redux Form it was empty. May I know how to do that to get the url inserts at Redux Form here? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
import React from 'React';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { change, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';

class UploadForm extends React.Component {
  onDrop = (accepted) => {
    if (!accepted.length) return;

    // start uploading
    this.setState({ isUploading: true });

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', accepted[0]);

    axios.post('upload', formData).then(
      (res) => {
        this.props.dispatch(change('uploadForm', 'url', res.url));
        this.setState({ isUploading: false });
      },
      () => {
        this.setState({ isUploading: false });
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(
  reduxForm({
    form: 'uploadForm',
    initialValues: {
      url: ''
    }
  })(UploadForm)
);
```

Please use this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you must use Field component from Redux-form.
Other wise, you can change form values using dispatch and change action creator.

```html
import { Field, change } from 'redux-form';

this.props.dispatch(change('uploadForm', 'url', this.state.url));
```

Comment: you mean put it like this:

<Field name="attachment" type="text" component={this.props.dispatch(change('uploadForm', 'url', this.state.uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl))} label="Attachment"/>

Comment: I still dunno how to do it, can you show the example on how to do it? Thank you

Comment: thank you for post the answer, I do it the method like this:

<input className="form-control" focus placeholder="attachment" type="text" name="attachment" ref="attachment" value={this.props.dispatch(change('uploadForm', 'attachment', this.state.url))} />

Comment: No, you don't have to use input tag. If you want to display url, just do like following: <Field type="text" component="input" name="url" />

Comment: if I using mapDispatchToProps may I know how to get the name from it, can you demonstrate the example for it also? thank you.